# Please remove the [faq] tag from the "Could we please be a bit nicer to the n00bs" question

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question

Consider

[Could we please be a bit nicer to new users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-the-n00bs-and-fresh-meat)

This seems 'too localized', as it describes someone's momentary reaction to a particular time in history. If it's a FAQ, shouldn't someone rewrite it to have a title like:

```
"How should we react to less than ideal first contributions?"
```

and have some sort of consensus answer that strikes a balance between rapid trash removal and welcoming potential useful contributors?

Comment: That question has been around for awhile.  It only appeared on your radar because @random made an ... er, random edit.  I'm inclined to edit it again to be a bit less condescending.  However, I do agree that it's a bit localized (and debate-like) for a FAQ entry.

Comment: It only then appeared on the radar from another flag @rob

Comment: "random" being a reference to the nature of the edit note. :P

Comment: Is it localized in time if it the sentiment [keeps occurring](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta/query/70835/be-nicer-to-new-users-dups)

Comment: Sure, that's a reason to have *a* faq entry, but this post did not strike me as being suitable as a faq entry.